# Debug Cordova Plugin

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

How do you debug the non-js portion of a cordova plugin? I have found several discussions on Stack Overflow, but none of them have given me an answer on how I throw my plugin into an IDE, and be able to breakpoint it.

Debugging the JS is no problem and makes sense, but I have no idea how to either print out a log from the android/ios side or hit breakpoints.

I am in the process of making a small change to InAppBrowser to allow Cookie read/writing and I desperately need to know how to monitor this.

Any help would be vastly appreciated.

Comment: create a cordova project, add ios and android platforms, add inAppBrowser plugin, and then, for iOS open the .xcodeproj on yourProject/platforms/ios, and for android, import the yourProject/platforms/android on android studio

Comment: Please make this an answer so I can give you proper credit. I never expected the answer to be so simple

Comment: Done, I've added more details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new cordova project

```
cordova create debugPlugins com.debug.plugis debugPlugins
```

go to the new folder

```
cd debugPlugins
```

add ios and android platforms

```
cordova platform add ios android
```

and the inAppBrowser plugin (or any other you want to debug)

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

When you added android and ios platforms, two native project where created, you can open and debug them.

- For ios, go to `platforms/ios` and open the debugPlugins.xcodeproj
- For android open android studio, go to File->New->Import Project and select the `platforms/android` folder

Comment: The key I was missing was the fact cordova exports native projects. Thanks!